# How do I appeal a Spanish visa refusal?

Tags: schengen, visa-refusals, spain, pakistani-citizens

What is the procedure to appeal a refusal of Spanish visa? I am resident and citizen of Pakistan and recently got refused for family visit to Spain. The refusal letter does not state where to send my appeal documents.

- What is procedure to appeal against Spanish visa refusal?
- Can I do it online or can I email the appeal documents somewhere?
- What is the address (postal or online/email) where I could forward my appeal letter & supporting documents?

Comment: From http://www.exteriores.gob.es/Embajadas/ISLAMABAD/en/InformacionParaExtranjeros/Pages/VisadosUniformeSchengen.aspx, "a contentious-administrative appeal may be lodged before the High Court of Justice of Madrid within two months after the notification date, or, optionally, an appeal for reversal before the same Diplomatic Mission or Consular Post within a month after the refusal notification date. "

Comment: The appeal forms appear to be available at: http://www.exteriores.gob.es/Embajadas/ISLAMABAD/en/Pages/req_forms.aspx#vus at the bottom of the page

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt response. I went through both links & got "In the event that a visa is refused, the applicant shall be notified by means of a standard form indicating the grounds for refusal. In this case, a contentious-administrative appeal may be lodged before the High Court of Justice of Madrid within two months after the notification date, or, optionally, an appeal for reversal before the same Diplomatic Mission or Consular Post within a month after the refusal notification date." Is there any email contact detail available for this Embassy for the appeal purpose please?

Comment: Just a quick comment, **usually** an appeal won't help unless they made some specific mistake. Look at your situation, especially employment and finances, and check if you provided all relevant documents.

Answer (score 2):

The [Embassy of Spain in Islamabad](http://www.exteriores.gob.es/Embajadas/ISLAMABAD/en/InformacionParaExtranjeros/Pages/VisadosUniformeSchengen.aspx) notes, that should you not be granted a visa, you will receive a written document or letter that says why you were refused. It will also tell you that you can appeal to the Consulate in Islamabad and/or to the High Court of Justice in Madrid. From the date of the refusal notice, you have 30 days to lodge your appeal at the Consulate, and 60 days in which to do so at the HCJ Madrid.

There is not an online portal nor should it be done via email. Rather, using the refusal letter, and addressing the stated reasons, you appeal to directly to the Consulate and/or the High Court of Justice in Madrid. The following are for reference and it is better to use the instructions contained in the refusal document/letter for how and where to appeal.

Spain’s Islamabad Consulate is located at Street 6, Ramna 5. Diplomatic Enclave I. 
Telephone office: (051) 208 87 77
Email: emb.islamabad@maec.es

Please be aware that questions about visa or Consular procedures are not responded to by phone or email, but are dealt with at the Embassy during normal office hours.

[Tribunales Superiores de Justica Madrid](http://www.poderjudicial.es/cgpj/es/Poder-Judicial/Tribunales-Superiores-de-Justicia/TSJ-Madrid/)
Calle del Gral. Castaños, 1, 28001 Madrid, Spain
Phone: +34 603 35 77 34