# How/where to submit Spain's visa rejection appeal from Algeria

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, spain, algeria

How do I make a Spain's visa rejection appeal in Algeria, what are the necessary documents?

And where I will send the rejection appeal?

Comment: What type of visa was refused?

Comment: And the decision has to include the process and where to send the appeal to the state that refused (Spain). What does your refusal letter direct you to do?

Comment: It's usually not a good idea to appeal a visa refusal.  Do you have a reason to think the appeal would be successful?  If you believe that your application was not strong enough and you want to submit additional evidence, you should not file an appeal; instead, you should submit a new application.  Appeals are typically limited to considering evidence that was available to the officer who made the decision being appealed.

Answer (score 3):

The [website of the Embassy in Algiers](http://www.exteriores.gob.es/Embajadas/ARGEL/es/InformacionParaExtranjeros/Paginas/VisadosUniformeSchengen.aspx) contains all the general information you need. See also the answer to [this similar question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/99067/how-do-i-appeal-a-spanish-visa-refusal).

The details on the process as well as the documents you need depend on the visa type, the reason for the refusal, and especially on what point of the refusal you want to contest and why. An appeal only makes sense if the decision is incorrect and unjust, it is not a way to "give it a second try".